# implement a function on a struct A that borrows another struct B?

Tags: rust, closures

In the process of an entity-component system, I'm having this issue where I want all my objects in my scene to be able to use methods on the scene as mutable.
However, I don't think keeping a reference to the scene is a good idea, as the scene is the structure containing the objects (so it would make a cycling reference), and I can't have multiple mutables references.

The idea that i got is that my objects have a function that borrows the scene : each time I want to do something on the scene from my object, I borrow the scene and then drop the borrow.

This is what I tried so far :

This is my Scene structure

```rust
pub struct GameScene {
    // array of all objects
    objects: Vec<GearObject>,
    components: ComponentTable,
}
```

And there is my object :

```rust
pub struct GearObject<'o, 's:'o> {
    transform: Transform,
    id: u32,
    get_scene: &'o dyn Fn() -> &'s mut GameScene,
}

impl<'s:'o, 'o> GearObject<'o, 's> {
    pub fn empty(id: u32, scene_borrow: &'s mut GameScene) -> GearObject<'o, 's> {
        // creates an empty gearObject
        return GearObject {
            id: id,
            transform: Transform::origin(),
            get_scene: &|| scene_borrow,
        };
    }
}
```

The idea was that my 'get_scene' would be a function that could borrow the scene
However, I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly, the code doesn't even compile ("cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'s` due to conflicting requirements")

Does this keeps a reference to my scene, or is it doing what I was expecting, only borrowing the scene when called?
Also, Why do I have a lifetime issue here ? am I not guaranting that my scene lives longer than my function to get it ?

Comment: No, this can't work as you have it written. Simply, it doesn't solve your problem -- your `get_scene` field might as well be `&'a mut GameScene`, because the closure you're creating extends the borrow of the `scene_borrow` argument. Further, you can't borrow a temporary closure if it captures from the environment. You'd need an owned closure, like `Box<dyn Fn() -> &'s mut GameScene>` but that would still extend the borrow of `scene_borrow`.

Comment: Even if you solve that, you effectively have a self-referential structure -- `GameScene` owns `GearObject` values, which have a reference back to `GameScene` (obscured by the closure right now) and [Rust doesn't like that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/501250) because if the `GameScene` value is moved in memory, the references it holds to itself become invalidated.

Comment: @cdhowie alright, so it won't work. Are there any ways for my GearObject to borrow the scene ?

Comment: `Rc<RefCell<GameScene>>` or `Arc<Mutex<GameScene>>` or change your function prototypes so that each function that wants to use the scene has a `&mut GameScene` parameter.

Comment: `Rc`/`Arc` can work, but you'll have a reference cycle.  The `GearObject` values should be given weak references, otherwise you'll have to manually empty `GameScene.objects` to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: Agree that if you really want to have that reference, it must be a `Weak` reference.